# can you explain me to add the specific user name in my discord python bot

Tags: python, discord

**recently, I'm making a discord bot**
I made a anti-swearing filter so in that when a person sends a bad word IT GETS DELETED and the person will receive message but then I got an idea to also send message in the server to let admins know so I tried this [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0cjx.jpg)
and this is what appears in discord [here in discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqXh7.jpg)
Please I need help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and [do not upload images of code when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, copy and paste the relevant code [with proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score -2):

If you want to put a variable inside your string you should use f-strings, and getting the author of the message, which could be done using:

```
f'The user {message.author.username} has sweared'
```

Here you'll understand more about f-strings: https://he-arc.github.io/livre-python/fstrings/index.html

Comment: how do you add this in a embed